# How to pass or use value from Lookup to Data Flow?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline working on ADF already, but I would like to try something by exporting Kusto data to ADLS instead of using the Copy activity (comparing performance as well).

So, is it possible to use a [Lookup activity value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) to a [Data Flow mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview)?

Lookup Kusto query:

```
let pickDate = datetime(2023-03-01);
let Conversion = datatable(Decimal: int, HexCode: string, Binary: string)
[
    0, '0', '0000',
    1, '1', '0001',
    2, '2', '0010',
    3, '3', '0011',
    4, '4', '0100',
    5, '5', '0101',
    6, '6', '0110',
    7, '7', '0111',
    8, '8', '1000',
    9, '9', '1001',
    10, 'a', '1010',
    11, 'b', '1011',
    12, 'c', '1100',
    13, 'd', '1101',
    14, 'e', '1110',
    15, 'f', '1111',
];
let data = materialize(range Dates from pickDate to pickDate step 1d
| extend Dates = format_datetime(Dates, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
| extend JoinColumn = 1
| join kind=inner
    (
    Conversion
    | extend JoinColumn = 1
    )
    on JoinColumn
| project Dates, HexCode);
let HexCodes = data 
| summarize make_set(HexCode);
data
| extend SubHexCode = toscalar(HexCodes)
| mv-expand SubHexCode
```

Output:

| Dates | HexCode | SubHexCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-03-01 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-03-01 | 0 | 2 |

What I need is to use the output from the Lookup query in my data flow instead of my pipeline, so the query will be similar to this:

```
set notruncation;
let HexCode = "@{item().HexCode}@{item().SubHexCode}";
Test
| where tolower(ContainerId) startswith HexCode
| join kind=inner (
    Test2
    | extend ContainerId = VmId
    | where startofday(TIMESTAMP) == startofday(datetime(@{item().Dates}))
    | where tolower(ContainerId) startswith HexCode
    )
    on ContainerId
| project x, y, z
```

[image: Current pipeline]

In the image above, I would change the CopyData actitivy to the DataFlow activity, and in the dataflow I would use a Kusto query with variables from Lookup value.

[image: Data flow]

**--- UPDATE ---**

Following @Rakesh answer, I changed my pipeline to have parameters and enabled the option "expression" for each parameter, but I still having troubles.

Also I dind't understand how can I use string interpolation to see the query output. This is my current pipeline:

High level:

[image: High level pipeline]

This is the parameters on the DataFlow activity:

I enabled the expressions for each parameter.

[image: Data Flow activity]

Inside the dataflow, this is the parameters set:

[image: Inside data flow]

This is the Kusto query with parameters:

I am doing `let HexCode = "$HexCode$SubHexCode";` because I need "00" from my lookup value. And using `| where startofday(TIMESTAMP) == startofday(datetime($Dates))` for the datetime.

The error I am still getting from the query below:

[image: Error]

**-- UPDATE 2 --**

Sample data for the Kusto:

| VmId | ContainerId | SampleCount | AverageCounterValue | CounterName | MinCounterValue | MaxCounterValue | PreciseTimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11c1b7c1-d1b1-11fb-11a1-0c711fe111c0 | 11c1b7c1-d1b1-11fb-11a1-0c711fe111c0 | 20 | 13.57497519 | Percentage CPU | 3.420510085 | 26.68882703 | 2023-03-08T05:04:59.9999999Z |
| 11c1b7c1-d1b1-11fb-11a1-0c711fe111c0 | 11c1b7c1-d1b1-11fb-11a1-0c711fe111c0 | 20 | 10.97057026 | Percentage CPU | 6.853699734 | 20.73203381 | 2023-03-08T05:04:59.9999999Z |
| 11c1b7c1-d1b1-11fb-11a1-0c711fe111c0 | 11c1b7c1-d1b1-11fb-11a1-0c711fe111c0 | 40 | 4.061182971 | Percentage CPU | 3.075506647 | 5.650666854 | 2023-03-08T09:54:59.9999999Z |

Comment: What do you mean by use look up values in dataflow? Provide an example of what you want to do

Comment: @SaideepArikontham I updated my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dataflow parameters for this.

This is the output for lookup of your query:

[image]

As you want to use the above values in dataflow in each iteration, create the dataflow parameters for those like below.

[image]

Pass the `@item().Date`, `@item().HexCode` and `@item().SubHexCode` to dataflow parameters inside ForEach like below.

[image]

You can use the above the dataflow parameters in your kustos query by using `$` before the parameter like `$Dates`,`$HexCode`,`$SubHexCode` as per your requirement.

Comment: Amazing explanation, but I am getting `Failed to parse datetime literal: 'datetime($Dates)'` message. On Kusto query I just add `$Dates` as a parameter? Because when I debug and the value "2023-03-08" as string it still doens't preview the output.

Comment: I always get hard time trying to debug ADF pipelines. How can I see the output query with values from parameters? It's not showing in the Monitor as we see when running a pipeline.

Comment: try to use [string interpolation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/evaluate-data-flow-expressions-inline-with-strings-in-adf/ba-p/1053589) in dataflow while using data flow parameters in the kustos query. Also try by changing the string to expression in the dataflow activity.

Comment: I updated my question to my current situation, I did same as you did and I still getting same error. I also didn't understand how to use string interpolation, there is no step by step on the doc nor the link above. Can you help me please? Will that be able to print the query I am using if I need to debug?

Comment: Since the original ask may get clumsy, I suggest you to raise a new question on your  current ask with all relevant details as kustos query also involved, so that the community also may assist you on that.

Comment: I can ask a new question regarding the string interpolation then. But I still need help on the main question, I still getting errors as I uploaded. Can you help me on the original question?

Comment: Can you help me with the sample data that you have given for the dataflow?

Comment: I updated my question to the Kusto sample data. Lookup sample data was already there.

Comment: I have given the answer for your ask here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75890693/how-can-i-use-string-interpolation-to-output-a-query-on-adf/75898027#75898027. Check if that helps.