# How can I use string interpolation to output a query on ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Following two guides, one from [Evaluate Data Flow Expressions Inline with Strings in ADF](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/evaluate-data-flow-expressions-inline-with-strings-in-adf/ba-p/1053589) and one from [Microsoft String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#string-interpolation) I couldn't be able to understand how can I output a query that I am using on a Data Flow activity to debug easier? It's possible to see a query input from a pipeline but easily done on a Data Flow.

Basically high level this is my pipeline:

[image: Pipeline]

And this is my data flow that is inside my ForEach activity:

[image: Data Flow]

In the data flow, I have a source that is executing a Kusto (Azure Data Explorer) query with parameters, something like this:

```
set notruncation;
let HexCode = "$HexCode$SubHexCode";
Table_1
| distinct ContainerId, VmId
| where tolower(ContainerId) startswith HexCode
| join kind=inner (
    Table_2
    | extend ContainerId = VmId
    | where startofday(TIMESTAMP) == startofday(datetime($Dates))
    | where tolower(ContainerId) startswith HexCode
    | where CounterName == "Percentage CPU"
    )
    on ContainerId
| project
    Column1,
    Column2
```

Multiline query:

```
let Conversion = datatable(Decimal: int, HexCode:string, Binary: string)
 [
  0, '0', '0000',
 1, '1', '0001',
 2, '2', '0010',
 3, '3', '0011',
 4, '4', '0100',
 5, '5', '0101',
 6, '6', '0110',
 7, '7', '0111',
 8, '8', '1000',
 9, '9', '1001',
 10,'a', '1010',
 11,'b', '1011',
 12,'c', '1100',
 13,'d', '1101',
 14,'e', '1110',
 15,'f', '1111',
 ];
Conversion
| where HexCode == {$HexCode}
```

How can I see the expected query output with values instead of variables when I run my pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve your requirement using String interpolation like below.

This is a sample data in ADX table named Table1:

[image]

For this sample demonstration, I have taken only one iteration of your lookup **i.e,** I have passed `Dates`,`HexCode`,`SubHexCode` from Pipeline variables to dataflow parameters directly like below.

The values for the pipeline variables, I have given as `2023-03-08`,`1`,`1` which are of string type.

[image]

In your case, you need to give these dataflow parameters values as `@item().Dates`, `@item().HexCode`, `@item().SubHexCode` inside ForEach.

**This is a sample query which involves the dataflow parameters and String interpolation**. Open the dynamic content of the query and given the query like below.

```
"set notruncation;let HexCode = '{concat($HexCode,$SubHexCode)}';Table1| where tolower(ContainerId) startswith HexCode| where startofday(PreciseTimeStamp) == startofday(datetime({$Dates}))"
```

Click on Open expression builder and give the above expression.

[image]

[image]

I have made the above expression for sample, you need to add your KQL query as per your requirement.

I have given a blob file in sink.

**Result after Pipeline Execution:**

You can see I got the records which satisfies the above query expression.

[image]

Also **Without String interpolation**, you can give the query expression using `concat()` function like below. But, I suggest to use String interpolation.

```
concat('set notruncation; let HexCode = "',concat($HexCode,$SubHexCode),'";Table1| where tolower(ContainerId) startswith HexCode| where startofday(PreciseTimeStamp)==startofday(datetime(',$Dates,'))')
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! I noticed that the query needs to be in only one line. So if I have a really big query, I would have to take some time to adjust it. Or is it possible to do in multiline? Can you try the second query from my question please?

Comment: The main question is still here also, can I output and SEE the query with their values? So I can debug it

Comment: I have checked it with multiple lines, but its not working. So giving it in a single line only might be the option here.

Comment: If you want to see the Data preview in Data flow, it will ask to provide manual values for the dataflow parameters. while debugging the pipeline it will work as it passes the values to it.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! That's why it wasn't working then. Regarding seeing the output, I not meant the Data Preview, I meant the input query that was given with the values from parameters, same as happens with pipelines. Is it possible?

Comment: No when you debug, the values from the lookup passed to the dataflow parameters in each iteration and you will get the output in sink if you give any dataset to sink. Here for showing the output I have given a blob file to sink. And when you use copy activity query option also you need to debug if you use any parameters or variables in the query.

Comment: I noticed that you didn't add the where clause: `where CounterName == "Percentage CPU"` into your example. Do I change the double quotes to single quotes when using string interpolation?

Comment: Yes, I tried with double quotes and its giving errors like transformation is invalid. In this case try with `where CounterName == 'Percentage CPU'`.

Comment: I created as an idea on Data Factory portal: [Allow multiline code as string interpolation on expression builder](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/012f77ea-e6cf-ed11-a81b-000d3ae6a6aa)